# Only change viewport size if on computer

Tags: html, css

So I am writing a website and for my desktop version I need this piece of html for everything to look good:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

But if I use that while on phone it messes up all of my layouts, so is it possible to only run that while on computer and skip it on phone?
Thanks

Comment: have you implemented the responsive design?

Comment: Yes, I have it is just that the phone version gets f'ed when I have that line in the html

Comment: Use CSS [```@media```](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp) tag

Comment: Bootstrap is not an option. This answer is misleading the OP.

Comment: @Amini, True. I deleted :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to skip this on a phone  then you can just delete it. On phone it messes up because you didn't do responsive design (read about media-query).

Comment: I have: media only screen and (min-width: 900). it is just that that is css, I do not know how to do it in html which was what I was asking